# "(key) field [@timestamp] not found" after restarting elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm attempting to use logstash to feed documents into elasticsearch which I could then query using the kibana web interface.  I am currently running a single elasticsearch node fed by logstash tailing apache access logs for testing purposes so that I can learn how to use logstash and elasticsearch before scaling up to multiple elasticsearch nodes in a cluster and log aggregation across multiple hosts and services with logstash.

I was able to successfully build an ES database last night by feeding it documents using logstash and I was able to query against it using kibana.  However, today, when I started my ES node again, I see the following error when attempting to run a query:

```
[2014-10-10 13:11:53,437][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Madam Slay] All shards failed for phase: [query]
```

(The full log is available [here](http://pastebin.com/hv7dhaa2).)

The health of my node seems to be just fine:

```
[pitserver ~/local/tmp/elasticsearch-1.3.4]% curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true"
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 2520,
  "active_shards" : 2520,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2520
}
```

I tried restarting the node several times.  The `data` directory ostensibly contains the same data that it did yesterday.

After learning a bit more about how kibana queries against elasticsearch, I believe that the most relevant error in the log file is this one:

```
(key) field [@timestamp] not found
```

I have learned that this error pops up when attempting to draw a histogram that contains date(s) that don't correspond to an existing logstash index in elasticsearch.  I have found an [(closed) issue report on kibana's GitHub page that describes the problem I am having](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/834).  The workaround is to only draw a histogram against dates that correspond to existing logstash indices in my elasticsearch database.

What doesn't make sense to me is that I was able to query by the timestamp field yesterday.  But elasticsearch has problems with the nonexistent timestamp fields today after restarting the elasticsearch cluster.

Why do I only see this problem after restarting elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You have an equal amount of unassigned_shards, these looks like replicas? Try disabling the replicas to get back to a cluster state of green and retry is my suggestion.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this and why you think removing replica shards would help?  I'm very new to elasticsearch.

Comment: curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    } }
'

Comment: I'm assuming that will disable all replica shards?  Why do you believe running this will help my problem?  It seems like the problem has more to do with the query that's being run from kibana, not with the shards in my elasticsearch database.